# Is the coevaluation map of finite-dimensional vector spaces always a mono?

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $k$ and denote by $V^*$ its dual.

Write $\eta:k\to V\otimes V^*$ for the "coevaluation map", i.e the unit of the adjunction making $V$ a dualizable object. Is $\eta$ always a monomorphism?

Comment: If the coevaluation is [the one defined on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Relation_to_dual_space), then it cannot be zero unless $V$ is zero, and a non-zero morphism starting at $k$ is a monomorphism.

Comment: But is $0$ considered a finite-dimensional vector space?

Comment: Yes, it is a finite-dimensional space.

Comment: Thanks! And what is the problem with zero? That it is an initial object? That it is terminal? Or something else? I mean structurally.

Comment: It is both an initial and a final object, but I don't see any "problem" with it.

Comment: But isn't a zero morphism a mono? I just don't understand why you had to separate the cases, since the answer is yes in both...

Comment: A zero morphism from $k$ to $\{0\}$ is **not** injective.

Comment: And that is, categorically, because $\lbrace 0\rbrace$ is an initial object, right? Thanks for your patience...I just want to see where this fails.

Comment: I think you lost me at some point.  You want to see where what fails?  In any case, no need for any category theory to see that any map from $k$ to $\{ 0\}$ is non-injective.

Comment: It might be interesting that this is false for modules over a ring. For example $\mathbb Z/25\mathbb Z$ is dualizable over $\mathbb Z/100\mathbb Z$, but the coevaluation $\mathbb Z/100\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/25\mathbb Z\otimes\mathbb Z/25\mathbb Z$ isn't mono. (Perhaps this isn't surprising because $\mathbb Z/25\mathbb Z$ is $0$-dimensional at a point of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb Z/100\mathbb Z)$, so this is really the same counterexample as before).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V$ is zero-dimensional, then the answer is no.

If $V$ is non-zero, then the answer is yes.  If $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, then the [coevaluation map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Relation_to_dual_space) is defined by
$$ k\to V\otimes V^*: \lambda \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda v_i\otimes v_i^*,$$
so it is non zero, and thus injective (since its domain is one-dimensional).